# How to create an npm script to first change directory and then run the application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

**Solution:**

I created another `package.json` to the "home" containing only a script for `cd src/` and `npm start`, the latter of which is defined in the original `package.json` at `src/` which contains another `npm start` script that finally runs the app.

---

**Question:**

I have my `index.js`, which is to be the *main* of my app, at path `C:\Users\Username\Projects\Project_name\src\index.js`. Also `package.json` is in the same directory and contains (among others) lines:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cd src/ && node index.js"
  }
```

**My intent is to** be able run my app by giving command `npm start` while in directory `C:\Users\Username\Projects\Project_name\`, i.e. the "home" directory of my project. Therefore I tried to specify the start script to first `cd` to `src` and then run `node index.js`. **This doesn't work though** which is presumably due to the "home" directory not containing the file that specifies the script. How to accomplish what I intend?

Error messages:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Username\Projects\Project_name\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Username\Projects\Project_name\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-26T10_55_18_132Z-debug.log
```

Comment: When you run an `npm` command, it looks for a `package.json` in your current working directory and  does not find it. You would need to `cd src && npm start`

Comment: @blex ok. Is this supposed to bypass the requirement of having `package.json` in the current working directory? EDIT: I created another `package.json` to the "home" containing only a script to `cd src/` and `npm start` the latter of which is defined in the original `package.json` in the `src` which then finally starts the app.